# How to switch between Audio and Video call in webRTC in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, webrtc, angular7

I integrated webRTC audio/video/screenshare code in my angular 7 application for conference calling purpose, which is done. Now the Video & Audio calling is working fine. My problem is, I need to achieve following things.

1. Mute & Unmute Audio while calling.
2. Switch Video call to Audio Call and vise versa while calling.

I have searched a lot and had no luck so far. It would be nice if you can give me any lead on these things. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you need to rechange your sdp beetwin users with the new media